# Changing UIViewController tab bar view to UINavigationController in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am trying to modify a newly placed `UITabBarItem` item from a `UIViewController` to a `UINavigationController` in XCode 4.

Here is a screenshot of a new view controller called "Near Me" and existing view controllers.

[image]

Notice how the new one is a `UIViewController`, I need this changed to a `UINavigationController`.

Something as simple as this was easily done in Xcode 3.2 and now that Apple has introduced Xcode 4 - it is just horribly difficult to re-learn this new IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify a `UIViewController` to be a `UINavigationController`. Even though a `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, its job is to manage other View Controllers, not Views.

In IB you should create a `UINavigationController` and then set the existing `UIViewController` as the root controller of the new `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in the menu on the right hand side. Just change the class. I hope this is what you are asking for.

[image]

Comment: If he already has other objects in the UIViewController then this is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

First you create window based application an in that `MainWindow.xib` file put tabBar Controller. Then delete that two `UIView` controller and add navigation controller under tabBar Controller. You can see below in screen shot.

[image]